# NameError in python unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am trying to test a python method of a `file-A` which uses a variable in `file-A`.
My `file-A` method looks like this:

```
def rotate(self, rotation):
    self.current_face = board.positions[(board.positions.index(self.current_face) + rotation) % 4]
```

> Note: This is inside class `A-1` in `file-A`

The `main` for `file-A` looks like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    inp = Input("input.txt")       # create Input object
    board = Board(inp.lines[0])    # create board object -----> NOTE
    rover_objects(inp.lines[1:])   # create rover objects
    process_and_print()            # process and print output
```

So, when I run `file-A`, it works exactly like I want it to work.

---

Now, I am trying to test `def rotate(self, rotation)` in `file-A`
My test code looks like:

```
class RoverTest(unittest.TestCase):
   def setUp(self):
       description = '1 2 N'
       moves = 'LMLMLMLMM'
       self.testRover = Rover(description, moves)
   def test_coordinates(self):
       self.testRover.rotate(rotation = 4)   -----> Problem
       self.assertEqual(self.testRover.current_face, 'N')
```

The issue is, `rotate` method in `file-A` uses the object `board` in the `main` in `file-A`
I am not sure how to pass `board` to the `rotate` function from the test.

If I run my test right now, I am thrown an error:

> NameError: name 'board' is not defined

How can I fix this error?

Comment: What is `testRover` and where is it defined?

Comment: Your method is called `rotate` but you are calling `rotation`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, sorry thought of editing that out in the post. Check now, thanks.

Comment: @jordanm, editing mistake. Can you check now, please? Thanks

Comment: `board` is only defined when your `file-A` as  a script, it  will  *not*  be defined when  you run  your tests, which  imports that  file as  a module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are writing a class that depends on other classes existing, you should make it accept those dependencies as arguments to the initialisation, rather than just hoping they are defined globally. For example:

```
class A1(object):
    def __init__(self, inputfile):
        self.inp = Input(inputfile)
        self.board = Board(self.inp.lines[0])

    def rotate(self, rotation):
        self.current_face = self.board.positions[(self.board.positions.index(self.current_face) + rotation) % 4]
```

Now in both your main and test files you can instantiate A1 directly by passing the input file.

This is just an example of course; you might want to instantiate the Board object outside the class and pass it in directly. Either way is fine, the important part is that you're passing in any dependencies.